# Link a row in a datatable

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to uniquely link each row of a table using the JQuery Datatables. The problem that I am running into is how I can store, or look up each unique link to each row of the datatable.  The table body is dynamically created from a database as such

```
echo "
    <table id='table_id' class='table table-striped'>
    <thead>
    . . .
    </thead>
    <tbody>
";

while($row) {
    // The uniquely value to represent the link to each row is
    // <a href ='rideinfo?PostID=$row[6]'></a>  
    echo "          
        <tr>
            <td>$row[1]</td>
            <td>$departDate</td>
            <td>$departTime</td>
            <td>$row[2]</td>
            <td>$returnDate</td>
            <td>$returnTime</td>
            <td>$$row[5]</td>
        </tr>                                   
     ";
     $row = $result->fetch_row(); 
}
```

The JQuery is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"          
    });     

    $("#table_id tbody tr").live('click',function() {   
        // I am not sure here how to store and get the id for each row
        document.location.href = "?PostID=" + id;       
    });                                     
});
```

Any help on how to get this value associated with each row would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give your while loop like

```
while($row) {
// The uniquely value to represent the link to each row is
// <a href ='rideinfo?PostID=$row[6]'></a>  
echo "          
    <tr id='<?php echo $row[6];?>'>
        <td>$row[1]</td>
        <td>$departDate</td>
        <td>$departTime</td>
        <td>$row[2]</td>
        <td>$returnDate</td>
        <td>$returnTime</td>
        <td>$$row[5]</td>
    </tr>                                   
 ";
 $row = $result->fetch_row(); 
}
```

and put jquery like

```
$("#table_id tbody tr").on('click',function() {   
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    document.location.href = "?PostID=" + id;       
});
```

replace **live** with **on** because it is deprecated.

Ratherthan that put a link on extra 'td' and give the link to your desired page like

```
<td><a href="my_url?postId=<?php echo $row[6];?>">LINK</a></td>
```

Comment: This works, but the problem that i am getting is with the pagination, for some reason the links are only working on the first page

Comment: Give me the pagination script..??

Comment: The pagination is done with  var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"          
    });     and it comes from the the JQuery datatables

Comment: at second page are you getting relevant data..??i mean correct data..?

Comment: I just checked the source of the page and all of the rows have the right data including the id= field, but for some reason the links do not work any page past the first

Comment: are you fetching record for pagination using ajax?

Comment: can you check by alert the id on each click at each page..??and moreover put this script at the ajax page(second page) also if it is there

Comment: I do not believe so, I looks like all of the data get put into the table properly and than the issue occurs with the pagination. Like it is not allowing events to happen on subsequent pages

Comment: @user1875195 have you checked..??